# Pushing value changed from one class to another

Tags: python

I'm trying to develop a kind of private API for my own hardware. I would like to have two classes, `Main` and `Simulations` in two separate python files. My `Simulations` class simulates push events from some third party hardware for debugging. I would like an easy way to receive these pushes in my `Main`. For example if I change the value of GPS coordinates in `Simulations`, I would like a `coordinatesDidChange()` method to get called. I would like to minimize the code in the `Main` and do all of the infrastructure stuff in `Simulations`. Any ideas?

**Psedocode**

```
class Main:
    def coordinatesDidChange(coordinates):
        # Do stuff with coordinates

class Simulations:
    coordinates = 0.0000
    coordinates = 0.2453
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20938/the-observer-design-pattern-in-python-in-a-more-pythonic-way-plus-unit-testing

Answer (score 0):

```
class Main(object):
    def notify_coordinates(self, long, lat):
        print 'Main received coordinates (%s,%s)' % (long, lat)

class Simulations(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.observers = []
        self.coordinates = {'long' : 0.0000, 'lat' : 0.0000 }

    def append_observer(self, observer):
        self.observers.append(observer)

    def update_coordinates(self, long, lat):
        self.coordinates['long'] = long
        self.coordinates['lat'] = lat
        self.notify_observers('notify_coordinates', long, lat)

    def notify_observers(self, callback, *args, **kwargs):
        for observer in self.observers:
            if hasattr(observer, callback):
                getattr(observer, callback)(*args, **kwargs)

main = Main()

simulations = Simulations()
simulations.append_observer(main)

simulations.update_coordinates(0.0000,0.2453)
```